# Unfilled Parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I wrote this block of code to format a list of URL-links.

```py
def main():
    format_link()
    create_html_link()

def format_link(dir_link_dirty):
    dir_link = dir_link_dirty.replace('"', "").replace(",", "").replace("\n", "")
    dir_link_code = urllib.request.urlopen(dir_link)
    bs_dir_link_code = BeautifulSoup(dir_link_code, "html5lib")
    h2_a_tag = bs_dir_link_code.h2.a
    html_link = str(dir_link) + "/" + str(h2_a_tag["href"])

    return html_link

def create_html_link():
    dir_lst = load_dir_file()
    for dir_link_dirty in dir_lst:
        html_link = str(format_link(dir_link_dirty))
        return html_link
```

If I run the code, I will receive this message:

> format_link(str(dir_link_dirty)) 
> NameError: name 'dir_link_dirty' is not defined 
> Process finished with exit code 1

What do I have to change to run it successfully?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. It might be causing some problems.

Comment: Did you check the `load_dir_file` return value?

Comment: The error you showed represents code that doesn’t exist anywhere in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking `format_link` in `main` there isn't an argument for `dir_link_dirty`.

broken:

```
def main():
    format_link()
    create_html_link()
```

fixed:

```
def main():
    format_link("https://example.com")
    create_html_link()
```

complete example:

```py
def main():
    create_html_link()

def create_html_link():
    dir_lst = load_dir_file()
    for dir_link_dirty in dir_lst:
        html_link = str(format_link(dir_link_dirty))
        print(html_link)
        return html_link


def format_link(dir_link_dirty):
    dir_link = dir_link_dirty.replace('"', "").replace(",", "").replace("\n", "")
    dir_link_code = urllib.request.urlopen(dir_link)
    bs_dir_link_code = BeautifulSoup(dir_link_code, "html5lib")
    h2_a_tag = bs_dir_link_code.h2.a
    html_link = str(dir_link) + "/" + str(h2_a_tag["href"])
    print(html_link)
    return html_link

def load_dir_file():
    return ["https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/ao_1977/BJNR006130976.html",
            "https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/ao_1977/BJNR006130976.html"]
```

Comment: In that case i would run my definition for only that URL. But I want to run the function on a variable, which is filled with different list-erntries each time.

Comment: But shouldn't you only invoke the create_html_method then? Did you check the return value of load_dir_file?

Comment: load_dir_file works it gives the list it shoudl give. I ll try to describe it closer:

Comment: @judgi could you try the updated example?

Comment: If I leave fromat_link(dir_link_dirty) away from def main(): it works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
create_html_link()
format_link(dir_link_dirty)


def create_html_link():
dir_lst = load_dir_file()
for dir_link_dirty in dir_lst:
    html_link = str(format_link(dir_link_dirty))
    print(html_link)
    return html_link

def format_link(dir_link_dirty):
dir_link = dir_link_dirty.replace('"', "").replace(",", "").replace("\n", "")
dir_link_code = urllib.request.urlopen(dir_link)
bs_dir_link_code = BeautifulSoup(dir_link_code, "html5lib")
h2_a_tag = bs_dir_link_code.h2.a
html_link = str(dir_link) + "/" + str(h2_a_tag["href"])
print(html_link)
return html_link
```

I´ll get the Links I need twice and the Error below

https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/ao_1977/BJNR006130976.html
https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/ao_1977/BJNR006130976.html

```
format_link(dir_link_dirty)
```

NameError: name 'dir_link_dirty' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1